# Como pasar una imagen de un Aactivity otro

Tags: java, android

***Tengo una imagen en el Imageview*** a través de  la galería y la cámara; y quiero pasarlo a otro Activity, ***mas abajo tengo el método cuando es un editext, no se como adaptarlo***:

***Galería***:

```
            imagen=data.getData();
            imgviewtomarfoto.setImageURI(imagen);
```

***Cámara***:

```
            imgviewtomarfoto.setImageURI(Uri.parse(guardarruta));
```

***Como podría adaptar este método Intent para la imagen:***

***Manda del PrimerActivity al SegundoActivity el dato***:

```
    Intent variable= new Intent(PrimerActivity .this, SegundoACtivity.class);
    variable.putExtra("datoApasar",editTextcorreo.getText().toString());
    startActivity(variable);
```

***Recibe en el SegundoActivity el dato del PrimerActivity*** :

```
    editTextcorreo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextcorreo);
    String dato=getIntent().getStringExtra("datoApasar");
    editTextcorreo.setText(dato);
```

Comment: ¿ Hay algun motivo en especial por el que quieras pasar la imagen? Lo Normal , es que captures la foto y la guardes en un archivo de imagen ( por ejemplo jpg), y luego pases el nombre de ese archivo entre Activitys, pero no si tu quieres hacer algo en especial...

Comment: si, mi aplicativo realiza una ecualizacion de histograma con OPENCV, si lo convierte, solo que quiero mostrar esa conversión en otro activity

Comment: Si creo que se pueden pasar Bitmaps sobre intents. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010386/passing-android-bitmap-data-within-activity-using-intent-in-android

Comment: te recomiendo revises un poco la documentación de como navegar entre fragmentos y compartir información https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/animate Saludos